# Tableau not loading custom color palette

Tags: tableau-api

I have edited `Preferences.tps` file from my tableau repository to add following code -

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<workbook>  
<preferences>   
<color-palette name="My Custom Palette" type="regular">     
<color>#75787B</color>      
<color>#A7A8AA</color>      
<color>#BBBCBC</color>      
<color>#B7C9D3</color>      
<color>#C6BCD0</color>      
<color>#E4D77E</color>      
<color>#D9C89E</color>
</color-palette>
</preferences>
</workbook>
```

Upon restarting the Tableau, I still can't see my color pallet in there. I tried searching online for possible solutions and have even replaced the code with custom codes available online. No luck though!

Comment: Double-check that Tableau is using the repository location that you think it is. In Tableau, go to [File -> Repository Location...]. Ensure that that is the location where you edited/saved the custom palette in preferences.tps.

Comment: Yes, I did that check. Its the correct location.

Comment: If I copy and paste exactly what you have above into my preferences.tps file, the custom palette shows up.  Make sure Tableau instance is truly being closed (or reboot computer). It might seem obvious, but are you searching for the palette in the correct place?  The palette above is for discrete data...if you are trying to find it on continuous data (ordered/sequential), it will not be there.

Comment: @S.User18 It seems, I am trying to find it on continuous data. How do I create a pallet for continuous data? Sorry for late response.

Comment: I added an answer on how to create a palette for ordered data. Review and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For continuous/ordered data, the type of the color palette would need to be "ordered-sequential" or "ordered-diverging".

See the link below for more info about creating a custom palette and with examples of various types.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/formatting_create_custom_colors.html

For example:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<workbook>  
<preferences>   
<color-palette name="My Custom Palette" type="ordered-diverging">     
<color>#75787B</color>      
<color>#A7A8AA</color>      
<color>#BBBCBC</color>      
<color>#B7C9D3</color>      
<color>#C6BCD0</color>      
<color>#E4D77E</color>      
<color>#D9C89E</color>
</color-palette>
</preferences>
</workbook>
```

Ordered-diverging above produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple versions of Tableau installed, try testing the custom colors on `default` one. it works.

[image]

Comment: What is  `default` ?